# Windows API hooking inc kernel and NTDLL. Is there an authoritative reference or teaching text?

Tags: hook

If a developer wishes to learn how to hook windows APIs and gain modifications control over the system as a whole, including

say, hooking into kernel functions, NTDLL

Windows Internals 5th Edition (PRO-Developer) (Hardcover)

Is this the ultimate authority on this subject?

if not, what is?

Answer (score 0):

The book you mention is very good.

For user space hooks, consider the following Programming Applications for Microsoft Windows by Jeffery Richter.